# pySpark Reduce throws Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop

Im a beginner with Spark, Hadoop and all the Big Data Ecosystem.

Im using Spark 3.0.1, Hadoop 2.7 and Python 3.6.

I have this .json file (json below is just an overview of the actual file) :

```
[{"number":122,"name":"122 - LOWER RIVER TCE / ELLIS ST","address":"Lower River Tce / Ellis St","latitude":-27.482279,"longitude":153.028723},{"number":91,"name":"91 - MAIN ST / DARRAGH ST","address":"Main St / Darragh St","latitude":-27.47059,"longitude":153.036046}]
```

And i want to parse it, do some data preparation on it then use KMeans to make clusters.

Here's what i did so far :

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

FEATURES_COL = ['latitude', 'longitude']
path = 'hdfs:/public/bikes/Brisbane_CityBike.json'
rdd = sc.textFile(path)

rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split('},{'))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace('[', ""))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace('{', ""))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: "{"+row+"}")

import json
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: json.loads(row))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: (row['number'], [row['longitude'], row['latitude']]))
```

When i try to reduce by : `rdd=rdd.reduce(lambda number, pos : pos)` i get the following error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-32-5db1324541cf> in <module>
    ----> 1 rdd=rdd.reduce(lambda number, pos : pos)

    /opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in reduce(self, f)
        842             yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
        843 
    --> 844         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
        845         if vals:
        846             return reduce(f, vals)

    /opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
        814         """
        815         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
    --> 816             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
        817         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
        818 

    /opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
       1256         return_value = get_return_value(
    -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1258 
       1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

    /opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
         61     def deco(*a, **kw):
         62         try:
    ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
         64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
         65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

    /opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
        327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329             else:
        330                 raise Py4JError(

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 16, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
        process()
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
        serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 400, in dump_stream
        vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "<ipython-input-17-aa02b6b59ccd>", line 2, in <lambda>
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 135 (char 134)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:357)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
        process()
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
        serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 400, in dump_stream
        vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "<ipython-input-17-aa02b6b59ccd>", line 2, in <lambda>
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 135 (char 134)

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:592)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:575)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1182)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:357)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

Anyone can help me up with that ? I'd be grateful.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the final closing curly `}` and square `]` brackets haven't been removed

```py
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace('[', ""))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace('{', ""))

//add the following
rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace(']', ""))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: row.replace('}', ""))
```

or you could consider letting the `json` package perform all the json extraction for you

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

FEATURES_COL = ['latitude', 'longitude']
path = 'hdfs:/public/bikes/Brisbane_CityBike.json'
rdd = sc.textFile(path)

import json
rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: json.loads(line))

rdd = rdd.map(lambda row: (row['number'], [row['longitude'], row['latitude']]))
```

Comment: Yea it worked lmao spent like 2h stuck on this..Thanks dude